# Ionic 4 plugin_not_installed on FTP plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am using `ionic 4` and the `ftp` **plugin.**

This is my **app module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { FTP } from '@ionic-native/ftp/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    FTP,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then this is my **home.page.html:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">

    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>

  <div>
  <h4>Success Message: {{ successMessage }}</h4>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <h4>Fail Message: {{ failMessage }}</h4>
    </div>

    The world is your oyster.
    <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And finally here is my **home.page.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FTP } from '@ionic-native/ftp/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  title = 'Test';
  successMessage = '';
  failMessage = '';

  constructor(private ftp: FTP) {

  this.ftp.connect('ftp_host', 'ftp_user', 'ftp_password')
  .then((res: any) => {
    console.log('Login successful', res);
    this.successMessage = `Login successful - ${res}`;
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
    this.failMessage = `Error - ${error}`;
  });


  }

}
```

The issue is that when I run this (running it on `IOS / Xcode Simulator` and `Device` too). 
I've tried running prepare so that it updates but the same error is still there.
I keep getting:

```
Error - plugin_not_installed.
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ftp
npm install @ionic-native/ftp
```

if you already install this plugin then remove `node modules` and `platforms` and re-install `node modules` and add `platforms`

Comment: Yes, the plugins were installed. I deleted node_modules and platforms folder ...run npm install and recreated the ios platform...I then run it and still have the same problem :(

Comment: also remove plugin folder

Comment: Done it 3 times and tested it but still the same error